# Finding the volume of liquid in a spherical tank

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates

Suppose there is a spherical tank partially filled with a liquid so that the liquid has a maximum depth of h. I want to find the equation for the volume of liquid in a tank in terms of depth h (and R for radius). I am thinking I should use a triple integral in spherical coordinates but I don't know what to make the bounds since the radius would vary with respect to theta and I want to keep the equation in a general form. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Spherical coordinates could work, yes. Cylindrical coordinates might be easier.

Comment: @aschepler How would I use cylindrical coordinates? Would I solve for z using the equation of a sphere and then convert the y and x components of z into spherical coordinates?

Comment: That works. You should find that the equation of the sphere in cylindrical coordinates is $r^2+z^2=R^2$.

Comment: @aschepler Since the equation of a sphere in cylindrical coordinates has not theta, do I still need to do a triple integral to find volume?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be known formula, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html

Mathworld also provides a step by step derivation for the spherical segment using integration.

Comment: The How To Answer help page: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible."